# What is the definition of convergence in the context of deep neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, convergence

Suppose I have a feed forward neural network which approximates a value, say $Y_0$. The analytical value of $Y_0$ is given. The plot of the network approximation of $Y_0$ each step is given as follows.

[image]

We can see (visually) that the approximation of $Y_0$ converges to its analytical value. But, how can we mathematically say that the approximation converges?

Note:
There is a definition of the convergence of a sequence.

> A sequence $\lbrace x_n \rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is said to converge to $x \in \mathbb{R}$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a natural number $K(\varepsilon)$ such that for all $n \geq K(\varepsilon$), the terms $x_n$ satisfy $\lvert x_n - x \rvert < \varepsilon$.

In this definition, the sequence is infinite and usually has certain *rules*, for example $\lbrace x_n \rbrace_{n=1}^\infty = \lbrace \frac{1}{n} \rbrace_{n=1}^\infty$. In fact, usually the approximation result of a feed forward neural network (or deep neural network in general) is a finite sequence which has the same number as the epoch/step. Is there a definition of convergence in the context of deep neural networks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The term is often used by the machine learning community loosely. When people say that “neural network converged” they mean that the training stopped improving. This could mean that they picked some arbitrary $\epsilon$ threshold and some metric that they use for tracking the progress of the training is changing from epoch to epoch by less than $\epsilon$. In other cases, it could mean that someone eyeballed the plot showing the training progress and decided that it looks “flat enough”.

Finally, there are no convergence guarantees as often in mathematics. The training can reach a minimum as measured with validation loss and then the loss can start getting worse as the model starts overfitting. Also reaching some point where it does not improve much does not mean that if you trained longer you would not get a better performing model or that other model would not be better.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know if it's appropriate or not to ask another question, but are there any (example) papers that use ϵ as you mentioned?

Comment: @poglhar that's any paper that mentions early stopping.